# getting started with gtkd

Tags: d, archlinux, gtkd

I'm new to D, and want to experiment with gtkd. I'm on arch linux, and installed the `dmd2-complete` (dmd 2.0.56) and `gtkd-svn` (gtkd built against D2) packages. I also verified that  D itself was working properly (compiled and ran a basic `writefln("hello world");` program).

Now I'm trying to get gtkd up and running, and am having a very hard time compiling and linking the basic helloworld program from the examples.

```
import gtk.MainWindow;
import gtk.Label;
import gtk.Main;

void main(string[] args)
{
  Main.init(args);
  MainWindow win = new MainWindow("Hello World");
  win.setDefaultSize(200, 100);
  win.add(new Label("Hello World"));
  win.showAll();

  Main.run();
}
```

Specifically, what options do I need to pass to dmd to get this to link? Pretty much all the documentation I can find skips over this entirely.

The `gtkd-svn` package has installed the following in /usr/lib:

```
 /usr/lib/libgtkd.a
 /usr/lib/libgtkdgl.a
 /usr/lib/libgtkdsv.a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer in the "related questions" sidebar. Leaving this up here since google didn't bring up the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897671/setting-up-a-working-d2-x-toolchain-with-gtkd-on-ubuntu-10-04) when I was searching, and it might have better luck with this one. You need to pass in the linker options as `-L-l`, specifically in this case

```
dmd -L-lgtkd -L-ldl hellogtk.d
```

and everything works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

dmd passes flags to the linker after the -L flag.

So I cannot say for certain, since I haven't used gtkD, but something like -L-lgtkd
should do the trick.

if not, play around with -L-lgtkdg1 and stuff..  one of em is bound to be right.

Edit: just adding extra info...
the linker will automatically search /usr/lib and a few other places.
I believe that the linker action is identical to the C process of linking, so more information can be gleaned from looking at how C links.

Comment: thanks, it was the -L-l syntax that was tripping me up! i tried every variant on -Lgtkd i could think of.

Answer (score 2):

I am programming on the *Gentoo* and I am manually compile *dmd* and *gtkD*.

So, at the start I type:

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

That gets me nothing.

I do that:
In `~/.bashrc:`

```
( ... )
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig
```

because there is all that we need.

Then I type:

```
pkg-config gtkd-2 --cflags --libs
```

and the output of this I copy and paste to:

     `/etc/dmd.conf`

to section: "[Environment]"

to variable: "DFLAGS" ( at the end ).

Clean install dmd and gtkD ( by copy and paste ) should look like that:

( /etc/dmd.conf )

```
( ... )
[Environment]
DFLAGS=-I/usr/include/phobos2 -I/usr/include/druntime -L--no-warn-search-mismatch -L--    export-dynamic -L-lrt -I/usr/local/include/d/gtkd-2/ -L-L/usr/local/lib/ -L-lgtkd-2 -L-ldl
```

At now I can compile my D programs like that:

dmd myprog.d

That`s all !

P.S.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also [pkg-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config):

```
dmd `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk-2`  hellogtk.d
```