# How to use gtkd on linux

Tags: linux, d, gtkd

I am trying to compile a hello world program using the gtkd library.
I am using the dmd compiler (installed into my ~/ directory) and I have already checked that the compiler works flawlessly.
Just in case, here is my source code:

```
//pragma(lib, "gtkd");
//pragma(lib, "dl");

import gtk.MainWindow;
import gtk.Label;
import gtk.Main;

void main(string[] args)
    {

  Main.init(args);
  MainWindow win = new MainWindow("Hello World");
  win.setDefaultSize(200, 100);
  win.add(new Label("Hello World"));
  win.showAll();

  Main.run();
}
```

The pragmas are commented out, because (if I understand this correctly) they do nothing more than the -L-l flags, nor did they get me any closer to a solution.
Anyways, after I save the file, I run:

```
dmd hello.d -L-lgtkd -L-ldl
```

and get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtkd
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

I already copied libgtkd-3.a, libgtkdgl-3.a and libgtkdsv-3.a into /usr/lib, but the output of the terminal remained the same.
I understand that the linker can't find my files, but I don't know how else I can help him do so.

For further info on my installation, I have set up everything exactly as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897671/setting-up-a-working-d2-x-toolchain-with-gtkd-on-ubuntu-10-04).
Not sure if it matters, but my computer is running crunchbang, a distro based on debian wheezy.
Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: Do not change the question title to Solved. Instead select the correct answer from the provided below, or submit your own! Thank you and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dmd hello.d -L-lgtkd -L-ldl
```

this try to find `libgtkd.a` but you does not have `libgtkd.a`, you have `libgtkd-3.a` so you must use:

```
dmd hello.d -L-lgtkd-3 -L-ldl
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are a lifesaver, thanks so much. I guess this is what happens when you only know a half of the truth about how something works.